# Loop in RewriteRule with [L] not working

Tags: .htaccess, loops, mod-rewrite

I know this has been covered, but I just can't find the answer to my problem.

For some years I had this page: www.mysite.com/page.php but decided to make it into a nice url: www.mysite.com/page/

That I did with:

```
RewriteRule ^page/?$ page.php [L]
```

All fine, but now I want it the otherway round as well, so if someone types in page.php, it will show /page/, but I just get a loop:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page/
RewriteRule ^page.php$ /page/ [R=301,L]
```

And I don't understand why. The [L] doesn't seem to work, but with [end] flag I get a 500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the correct way of doing this. You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from /page.php to /page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(page)\.php[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]

# internal forward from /page to /page.php
RewriteRule ^(page)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: ...thanks very much, this helps me a lot! I added a / to the first rewrite to get the trailing slash: RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=302,L]

Comment: BTW why 302 and not 301?

Comment: `302` is good for testing the rule. Once verified change it to `301`